# Linking Error in C++ development in Visual Studios 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I am doing c++ porting/development in visual studios 2008.
I am getting the following issues.

1) Variable sized array not allowed.
2) Linking error for any of the undefined functions of the class even if they are not referenced.(error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall ...)

I think these are related to the version of the c++ language VS2008 support.

I am trying a compile and link large c++ codebase. I cannot substitute variable sized array with new/alloc. Please give me solution so that I can use the existing code.

Can anyone please help me sort this out?

But the following code works fine in the same VS2008

```
class Hello
{
public:
    int a;
public:
virtual void add();
};
class bye : public Hello
{
public:
    int y;
public:
    void add();
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "got";
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, VLAs aren't allowed in *any* standard version of C++.

Comment: I am trying to port c++ code from linux to windows. g++ support VLAs

Comment: Yeah, as an extension.  As you've found, Visual Studio doesn't.  That's about the end of it.  If you really "cannot substitute variable sized array with new/alloc" you're out of luck.

Comment: @CarlNorum Is that the case for both the issues I am getting?

Comment: Your other problem is easier - just implement the functions.

Comment: @CarlNorum No other solution?...This is very large framework which runs fine with gcc on linux...I will have implement like 300 functions for it to run on VS2008

Comment: Why don't you just use GCC for windows, then?

Comment: @CarlNorum Can you please comment with my updated question?

Comment: Why do you think this example program has anything to do with your real problem?  The linker can certainly do different things with different programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual functions are considered "used" if you have a single instance of a class created anywhere. Your link error indicate that certain virtual functions are not implemented. As the error list all of them by name it must be a trivial task to locate them, end figure out if you failed to include some code, compiled with different options, or they were indeed unimplemented in the source place -- in which case you can just add blank implementations calling terminate.

For the VLA problem: that extemsion is not present in VS2008, period. Even if you wait some years and VS201y will implement the new VLA-like thing in C++14, it will not go back to your chosen compiler. (kinda weird if you ask me to chose a 5-year old bug-ridden beast that has dropped of support long ago, instead of the current...)

But `std::vector` does almost the same as VLA, and if you find difference you can write a beter wrapper or a few adapter functions. The place of memory allocation is not something you can discover legally in the program anyway. In case you'd hit some performance bottleneck, that is doubtful from such a change, you can rearrange a small portion of code.

Answer (score 0):

How about use std::vector to replace the arrays?

Comment: It compiles because you never use/call any of the classes or class member functions. In your example, everything is declared but never used.